# why is warning "cannot resolve symbol"- "intent"

Tags: android, android-intent, symbols, destroy, speech

I'm trying to "destroy" an "ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" intent...

```
public  void getSpeech(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
```

...

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leaks when activity is destroyed
    ....stopListening();
    ....cancel();
    intent.destroy();
    intent. getInstance().shutdown();
    super.onDestroy();
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? onDestroy() is not guaranteed to be called. If you need to do some cleanup when the app is put in background, do it in onStop or in onPause depending on the Api you are targetting.

Answer (score 0):

You have been declaring your `intent` variable locally inside `getSpeech(View view)` method. You should be declaring your variable globally.

```
public class YourClass {
  Intent intent = null;
  ...
}
```

Inside `getSpeech(View view)` method,

```
intent = new Intent(...);
```

Inside the `onDestory()` method,

```
if (intent != null) {
  intent.destroy();
  intent.getInstance().shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent object is created inside the method that means when the method finishes execution. the local members created in that method will be garbage collected by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting `intent` as a field on your Activity, rather than locally inside the method. Do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your view, etc.
    }

    public  void getSpeech(View view){
        intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // prevent memory leaks when activity is destroyed
        ....stopListening();
        ....cancel();
        intent.destroy();
        intent. getInstance().shutdown();

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

This should accomplish what you're looking for.
Keep in mind if you haven't called getSpeech, `intent` will be null, in which case inside `onDestroy()` you would get a `nullPointerException`, so you should check for null before calling `intent.destroy()` and `intent.getInstance().shutdown()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, you can press Ctrl+Alt+L and select organize imports.

Comment: How does this answer the question?